# How do i change the size of the box for my collision bounds?

Tags: game-engine

[image: You see the size of the box, how do I make it bigger]My object always falls through the floor at the end of the box that shows the collision bounds. How can I adjust the size of it?

Comment: Could you be more specific and/or include a screenshot?

Comment: @ShadyPuck ok I have one

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the drop down menu labeled `Box` under the collision bounds panel to `Convex Hull`, or `Triangle Mesh` if the first doesn't work. Also, if it is still falling through the floor, try upping the substeps from 1 to 5 under *Properties Editor>World>Physics>Physics Steps:>Substeps*. If none of this helps, or if it does and you want to learn more, Blender Cookie has some good game engine tips at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QY7iJmqsJf8

Hope this helps and happy Blending!